# Doing post-hoc power analysis on a simple effect

Tags: statistical-power, post-hoc

I tested an interaction in a correlative study (N = 220). The interaction was non-significant but one of the simple effects was. Is it somehow possible to calculate power based on this simple effect? Because both variables were continuous I don't have an exact number of participant in the "cell" in which I found the simple effect.

Answer (score 1):

Post hoc power is a misleading and fallacious concept. Don't do it.

For an in-depth argument, see [Hoenig & Heisey, "The Abuse of Power - The Pervasive Fallacy of Power Calculations for Data Analysis", *The American Statistician*, 2012](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313001300339897).